# Hive Conditional logic if or case

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following conditional statement i am trying to convert into hive

```
if [my_time] > [your_time] then [my_time]
elseif isNull ([your_time])
then [my_time]
else null()
endif
```

Also my_time and your_time are in timestamp formats. I have tried the following below in hive but it doesn't seem to be correct as some expected results are missing

```
case when (my_time > your_time) then my_time
     when (your_time = Null) then my_time
end as overall_time
```

How can i fix my logic in the second statement above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` can't be compared with an equal to `(=)` Use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`.
Your logic is equivalent to

```
case 
     when your_time IS NULL
     OR my_time > your_time 
     then my_time
end as overall_time
```